# Why xcode-select: error :command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Tags: macos, terminal

i wanted to:   brew install macvim --override-system-vim
meet a problems:

> macvim: A full installation of Xcode.app is required to compile this   software.
>   Installing just the Command Line Tools is not sufficient.
>   Installing just the Command Line Tools is not sufficient.
>   Xcode can be installed from the App Store.
>   `Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.`

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 8):

You need to install the Xcode first and if you already have it.
Try

1. Remove the old tool in your terminal

   sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
2. Install it again

   xcode-select --install